# AWK - Match Field1, Insert Field 2 into Field 2

Tags: awk

I know this is a simple logic with AWK but I cannot figure it out.  I've used "join" to do similar tasks or splitting, but I'd like it written in AWK.  Can someone provide this?

**File1**

```
JASON   11  BLACK
JOHN    19  BROWN
JOSH    13  GOLD
```

**File2**

```
JOHN    5910
JOSH    5711
JACOB   1980
JIMMY   1050
JASON   9614
```

**Output**

```
JASON   9614    11  BLACK
JOHN    5910    19  BROWN
JOSH    5711    13  GOLD
```

Comment: @BillDoughty you don't know awk.

Comment: OP, there are many many similar questions and solutions on SO, you should do some search at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following `awk` may help here.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2 OFS $3;next} ($1 in a){print $1,$2,a[$1]}' FILE1 FILE2
```

Comment: What if I had a 3rd field in file2 and also want to add that (as a 3rd column in the output file)?

Comment: @user3746195, change `$1`,`$2` to `$0` in case of printing whole line.